# Is there any free API to get historical forex exchange rates?

Tags: api, finance

There are several free services for getting the live price or download historical data for 1M or 1D charts.

I wonder if there is a free API service to get the data (OHLC) for a specific date of 1D chart or DateTime of 1M chart?

Comment: duplicate? https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/9333/1511

Answer (score 1):

You can access foreign exchange rates from the [Federal Reserve Economic data](https://public.enigma.com/search/foreign%20exchange%20rate?collection_id=27b38b43-451b-4407-8688-5cc4ca49ba7b). You can access this open data via [Enigma Public](https://public.enigma.com/) and make use of their free [API](http://docs.enigma.com/public/public_v20_api_about.html). You need to [sign up](https://public.enigma.com/signup) for an account to do so but it's free.